# Website-layout : Shall I use CSS-width with percentage or flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got to make a three column layout.

I like to make it with width-declarations which use percentage as unit.

Now someone told me I should use flexbox instead. Would be safe enough from at this time because all modern browser support it.

Might be right because there is no special requirement to support legacy-browers.

But still not sure if flexbox is really better and therefore asking:

Are there drawbacks when using flexbox instead of the "classical" way with widths?

Or the other way around asked: Does the width-technique still have benefits over flexbox. So that I should stay with that?

Comment: there are no drawbacks as such and use the width property in the parent and it should work..

Comment: Sorry , but this should be closed as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no drawbacks but for more advanced layouts I recommend flexbox because you have some useful features like flex-direction, flex-wrap, flex-shrink, align-items, order, ... and these options are more complicated if you use percentages everywhere.

You can find a nice tutorial here: [A guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I believe flexbox is quite simple to use so I'd recommend it.
I never use width percentage on layout.
I used to use bootstrap grid template. That's quite good too to my opinion

Comment: Bootstrap grid is width with percentages...